# How to know in our Application in Photos app is updated

Tags: iphone, ios7, photo, assets, alasset

My application is based on Photos app,

I am using photos from photos app and in our app I am adding tag in photos, 
So how can I check in photos app photo is deleted or added via camera,

Is there any method to know photos app is updated (delete photo or add photo).

Comment: I think you mean camera roll, not photos app, please post more details on how you get photos for the first time.

Comment: For get photo i am use ALAsset.

Comment: Since you are using ALAsset to get photos, then you are on the right track.
If you are saving the photos metadata, then you shouldn't, just refresh your UI every time your app is launched.

Comment: For this in my case if photo is deleted in photo app then how my app is know which photo is deleted, is there any way to get URL of that deleted photos ?

Comment: you want to keep track or just show the current? If you want to keep track, then you need to store the photos metadata every time you refresh & compare the current to the stored